# Why are my htaccess redirects rewriting my URLs instead?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm trying to implement 301 redirects via htaccess but they're not behaving as expected. For example, if I take a sample of the redirects in the order they appear in htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /hello/ https://www.example.com/goodbye/
Redirect 301 /hello/orange/ https://www.example.com/fruit/orange/
Redirect 301 /hello/apple/ https://www.example.com/fruit/apple/
Redirect 301 /hello/pear/ https://www.example.com/fruit/pear/

</IfModule>
```

Instead of each page redirecting to it's correct destination, any URL that contains the first line as a portion of it's URL gets rewritten. So any URL with /hello/ has that portion rewritten to /goodbye/ - the actual results for the above end up being:

```
/hello/ - > https://www.example.com/goodbye/
/hello/orange/ - > https://www.example.com/goodbye/orange/
/hello/apple/ - > https://www.example.com/goodbye/apple/
/hello/pear/ - > https://www.example.com/goodbye/pear/
```

I've confirmed this effect by reordering the redirects. If we place that first redirect at the bottom, then all the redirects work correctly.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the documentation, it explains that the Redirect directive treats the URL-path as a prefix only - anything *starting with* the argument you supplied, will get rewritten.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect:

> Then any request beginning with URL-path will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.

Comment: Thanks. So do you know what the correct approach would be to solve this?

Comment: You already discovered that it works when you put the rules in the / an appropriate order. So what is left to solve then …?

Comment: Essentially we're working with a team that wants to be able to add redirects ad-hoc to the list - ideally I'd like to give them the ability to add them to the end of the list rather than have to figure out where they sit in the order every time

Comment: That is not really possible. Consider this something a bit like a “recipe”, food preparing instructions - yes, you can crack the eggs first, and only fetch the pan later - but that gives you eggs on the floor, and not an omelette. These things need to happen in the correct order. There is no way for the server to determine that it should not do what it was instructed to do based on a request path `/hello/`, because some more specific instructions might come at a later time.